# Laravel Postgis generate Point object

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, postgis

I am developing a system with Laravel framework using Postgres database with Postgis. the database has a table with a geometry field (3D Point). so I need to convert 3 dimensions to Point object and Point objects to 3 dimensions.

I searched for Laravel Postgis library and I found [laravel-postgis](https://github.com/phaza/laravel-postgis), but it just developed for 2D point and has no support for 3D points. therefore I decided to use directly or develop a convert function in php for using in Laravel.

Some code I tried for insert new data directly :

```
$arr = ['geometry' => "ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || " . Input::get('Latitude') . " || ' ' || " . Input::get('Longitude') . " || ' ' || " . Input::get('Altitude') . " || ')', 4326)"];
Location::where('id','1')->update($arr);
```

the sample initialize of $arr variable is like

> ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || 1 || ' ' || 1 || ' ' || 1 || ')', 4326)

It's like something I found in [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/st-makepoint-or-st-pointfromtext-to-generate-points)

But Laravel debug got errors to me :

```
PDOException in Connection.php line 384: SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry

SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry (SQL: update "DBLocation" set "geometry" = ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || 1 || ' ' || 1 || ' ' || 1 || ')', 4326) where "id" = 1)
```

I want to know my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax of parametrized queries, but it should be something like this:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%, %, %), 4326);
```

with three parameters: `Longitude`, `Latitude`, `Altitude` **in that order!**

Comment: I think you didn't pay attention to reported errors. the error is about something parsing **ST**.

Comment: I'm saying ST_PointFromText is the most error prone and least efficient way to construct a geometry, and suggesting the normal way (which avoids the reported error). However, I'm unsure of how this should be adapted for Laravel.